# IE7/8 css issue with rotating div content

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a div that contains a table. On the click of a button in the table, I want to rotate the div and its contents by 90 degrees and hide everything but the header offscreen. Here is an example of this working in IE10:

[image: what I want to happen]

However, this does not work in IE7 and IE8. Inspecting the elements via the developer toolbar, it seems that the table is not rotating. The div seems to be rotating, because the outline appears where it should be... However, it's like the actual UI isn't updated to reflect this rotation?

[image: what is happening]

Any ideas what might be happening and how to fix this?

Some relevant css for IE7:

```
#my-div {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-height: 35px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#my-div.hide
{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 35px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
}

#my-div table
{
    width: auto;
}
```

And the html is nothing special. It's laid out like this:

```
<div id="my-div">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <button>X</button> 
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr> 
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS code without the associated html markup is useless. Have you tried to set the filter to the table element itself, too? Might be helpful, if you set up an online example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using developer tools to switch between browsers. Apparently, this changes some browser security settings. The way this would actually look in IE7/IE8 is not accurately represented by using developer tools in IE10.

I downloaded IETester, and the content is not having this issue anymore. False alarm.

Comment: Check out the Virtual Machines Microsoft is providing free for testing older version of internet explorer. I have had best luck using virtual box and the virtual box images! http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work for IE7. If you are unable to get it work there is a JavaScript Library called [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/#more-896) that allows you to use CSS code for rotations and works for older versions of IE.

Edit: I was playing with the example code from the [MS Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and noticed that their example works fine on all versions of IE. If I change the `position:` to `relative` instead of `absolute` the rotation stops working in IE7. You might want to test that on your end since you are using relative positioning on your element.

If that does not help you a full sample of your HTML code or a fiddle would be helpful so that the community could better help you.

Answer (score -1):

on associated click event of the button use jquery to rotate the div and all its children

```
function changeOrientation(){
$('#div').attr('webkit-transform', 'rotate(90deg)'); 
//Loop inside all elements in the div and add the same to all the elemnt

}
```

javascript code

```
function changeOrientation(){
    document.getElementById('#div').style.webkit-transform = 'rotate(90deg)'; 
    //Loop inside all elements in the div and add the same to all the elemnt
for(var count = 0; count < document.getElementById('#div').children.length; count++){
document.getElementById('#div').children[count].style.webkit-transform = 'rotate(90deg)'; 
}
}
```

give a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: What makes you think that a prefixed webkit-transform property would work in IE7/8? On top of that, css properties aren't standalone HTML element attributes, as your first example suggests.

Comment: Have no idea on ie7 or 8 since mine one is 10 . Just gave a try as for the one whos looking for a solution it might work :)